# How do mock handler.postDelayed with Mockito?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I a beginner on Mockito/Junit Tests. I need to coverage this code in Android Studio IDE and i don't know to do it. I need to mock Handler and postDelayed() function too.

Code i need to coverage:

CropSettingViewHandler.java

```
 Handler h = new Handler();
            if(dataHandler.isCropSettingsFirstAccess()) {
               h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                     cropSettingsView.getCropTypeInfoButton().performClick();
                  }
               }, 100);
               dataHandler.setCropSettingsFirstAccess(false);
            }
         }
```

CropSettingViewHandlerTest.java

```
@Test
public void testCropSettingsFirstAccess()  {
        ArgumentCaptor<CategoryButtons.CategoryButtonsEventListener> categoryButtonEventListerCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(CategoryButtons.CategoryButtonsEventListener.class);

        when(mockCropSettingsView.getCropSettingsCategoryButton()).thenReturn(mockCategoryButtons);
        verify(mockCategoryButtons, times(1)).setCategoryButtonsEventListener(categoryButtonEventListerCaptor.capture());

        CategoryButtons.CategoryButtonsEventListener catergoryButtonEventListener = categoryButtonEventListerCaptor.getValue();
        catergoryButtonEventListener.onCategoryButtonsAfterExpand(mockCategoryButtons);
        catergoryButtonEventListener.onCategoryButtonsBeforeExpand(mockCategoryButtons);
        catergoryButtonEventListener.onCategoryButtonsAfterCollapse(mockCategoryButtons);
        catergoryButtonEventListener.onCategoryButtonsBeforeCollapse(mockCategoryButtons);

        when(mockDataHandler.isCropSettingsFirstAccess()).thenReturn(true);
        Assert.assertEquals(mockDataHandler.isCropSettingsFirstAccess(),true);


        ArgumentCaptor<Runnable> runnableArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Runnable.class);
        Runnable runnable = runnableArgumentCaptor.getValue();
        runnable.run();

        verify(mockCropSettingsView).postDelayed(runnableArgumentCaptor.capture(),100);
}
```

i need help to coverage with mockito/junit

Comment: I cannot find the `CropSettingViewHandler` method called in the test method, only find mock and verify. You need to trigger a method of `CropSettingViewHandler` in test method.

Comment: On the other hand, you could use `doAnswer(invocation -> {invocation.getArgument(0).run()}).when(h).postDelayed(any(Runnable.class))` to instead of `ArgumentCaptor`